# How many non-NaN values should a column have for a non-NaN corrwith() result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-analysis

The *ratings* dataset contains the following columns - *movie_id, title, user_id, rating*.

```
movieRatings = ratings.pivot_table(index = ['user_id'],columns = ['title'],values = 'rating')

starWarsRatings = movieRatings['Star Wars (1977)']
similarMovies = movieRatings.corrwith(starWarsRatings)
x = movieRatings[['Star Wars (1977)','3 Ninjas: High Noon At Mega Mountain (1998)']]
```

There were several NaN values in the pivot table as all the movies had not been rated by all users (as specified in the code).

Now, in *SimilarMovies* series, I could see a few NaN values, one of them was for the movie/column '*3 Ninjas: High Noon At Mega Mountain (1998)*'. So I extracted the columns *Star Wars (1977)* and *3 Ninjas: High Noon At Mega Mountain (1998)* of *movieRatings* and stored it in *x*. After dropping the rows with *3 Ninjas: High Noon At Mega Mountain (1998)* as NaN, I got the following results.

| user_id | Star Wars (1977) | 3 Ninjas: High Noon At Mega Mountain (1998) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 13 | 5 | 1 |
| 206 | nan | 1 |
| 537 | 4 | 1 |
| 609 | nan | 1 |

I was surprised by this because I expected no user to have rated both these movies (since the corrwith() result corresponding to *3 Ninjas: High Noon At Mega Mountain (1998)* was NaN) but turns out there were 3 such users. Could someone give me some insight so that I can reason this out?

My question (which I'm not sure is correct) is: What is the threshold value for non Nan values in a column so that the corrwith() is not NaN?
Thanks in advance.